# Showing Query to a Toast

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

Im trying select specific fields from my database that would match the item that was clicked in my listview, when i run the app and clicked any item a app crashes, What is wrong in my code?

Here is the error from logcat

```
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "General": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT Region,City,Address,Contact FROM tblHospitals WHERE HospitalName = Bernardino General Hospital
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at com.dr.droid.lee.Health.onListItemClick(Health.java:54)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1071)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2527)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3181)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
11-28 16:08:50.168: E/AndroidRuntime(27284):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my class file

```
public class Health extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.health);
        displayHospitals();
        }

    public void displayHospitals (){
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        DbHelper tblHL = new DbHelper(this);
        tblHL.open();
        ArrayList<String> result = tblHL.getHData();
        result = tblHL.getHData();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result));
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

         tblHL.close();
         }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String hosp = (String)getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String quer = "SELECT Region,City,Address,Contact FROM tblHospitals WHERE HospitalName = " +hosp ;
        SQLiteDatabase mydb = openOrCreateDatabase("dbDrDroid", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery(quer, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        Toast.makeText(this, c.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


}
```

Comment: put the hospital in quotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do like this to make sure that your query handles the spaces in the hospital name correctly:

```
String quer = "SELECT Region,City,Address,Contact FROM tblHospitals WHERE HospitalName = \"" +hosp + "\"";
```

Comment: thanks sir, the app is not crashing but it displays a wierd toast message "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40e8e230"

Comment: You are trying to put a String representation of your cursor as the message: c.toString(). Make sure to first get the proper column from the cursor, and then the value for that column. Use that in your toast. Something like: c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MESSAGE_ROW_ID));

Comment: how do i do that sir? im sorry im new to android programming.

Comment: i changed my toast to this:Toast.makeText(this, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Region")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); the app crashed again

Comment: Try to enclose that particular snippet in try.. catch{} block and find out what exception it throws exactly.

Comment: And you have a row in your database named "Region" (case sensitive) that contains Strings? Please post the error message you see in LogCat, and I'll try to help you.

Comment: it now shows the correct region sir, when i posted the error i tried to remove the c.Movetofirst and i just wrote it back and it is properly displaying the correct region. how do i concatinate the other 3 fields?

Comment: String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Region") + " " +  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("City") + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address") + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Contact"); Should do the trick. Just a friendly reminder. A dialog might be better than a toast with this much (and probably important) info. The toast will time out and maybe not give the user a chance to read everything.

Comment: working perfectly sir, thanks for the reminder. i am just testing the method if it can display it properly, my next goal is to put those 4 fields in extras in display it in the next activity. Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the following row

```
String quer = "SELECT Region,City,Address,Contact FROM tblHospitals WHERE HospitalName = '" +hosp+"'" ;
```

because `HospitalName` is a text

Comment: thanks sir, the app is not crashing but it displays a wierd toast message "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40e8e230"

Comment: Still it means, you are trying to show up the cursor reference directly as string.